# Redirect to a URL if query string is not completely given

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I wanted to frame Rewrite rule condition for Apache if the query string is not completely available. Below is the scenario:

This is the working URL format -

```
https://<base_url>/redirect_uri#state=<value>&token=<value>
```

If the URL is coming like `https://<base_url>/redirect_uri`, I wanted to redirect to the login page.

I tried as below which is not recognizing the parameter

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^#state [NC]
RewriteRule ^/redirect_uri$ https://<base_url>/login [R=301,L]
```

Please help me to correct the condition to recognize the parameter

Comment: The part `#state=&token=` is an anchor and is not sent to the server. Besides, if your `RewriteRule` is in a .htaccess file, the path tested by RewriteRule never starts with a `/` (= it will never match your pattern)

Comment: There is no "[query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)" in the example URL you've given. The part after `#` in the URL is called the "fragment identifier". You cannot perform this redirect in `.htaccess` (ie. server-side) for the reason given in @julp's comment.

Comment: I have to do this RewriteRule in Apache configuration file which is in proxy server, not in a .htaccess file

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's in `.htaccess` or main server config, you cannot do this server-side in Apache since the fragment identifier (fragid) is not sent to the server (the browser does not send this as part of the HTTP request). The fragid is for client-side use only. As far as the server is concerned there is no difference between `https://<base_url>/redirect_uri#state=<value>&token=<value>` and `https://<base_url>/redirect_uri`.

Comment: Ok understood. Thanks for the clarification @MrWhite